# How can I make Latex respect empty lines when using lstlisting package?

Tags: listings, verbatim, sourcecode

How do I get Latex to respect empty lines when using the `lstlisting` command? If I put in several empty lines between two rows of text they reduce to a single empty line. Is there a way to make Latex leave this empty lines in the document?

Answer (score 6):

The `listings`-package provides an option for the maximum number of empty lines displayed named `emptylines` (see the package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)).

However by default, empty lines are printed:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
test


test

test



test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the usage of `emptylines`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{emptylines=1}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
test


test

test



test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]